# How does stdio buffer works in this case?

Tags: bash, buffer

I've been studying how stdio buffering works. I read the links [1] and [2] below but there are two points I still don't understand.

In [2], he uses the following bash script to write output intermittently and then he uses the piped commands:

```
#generator.bash
for i in {1..1000}; do
  echo "this is line $i"
  sleep 1
done
```

```
bash generator.bash | grep --line-buffered line | cut -c 9-
```

I understand why he had to use --line-buffered with grep, but why doesn't he have to do something similar about the stdout buffer from "bash generator.bash"? I can only imagine that this stdout buffer is line buffered but I couldn't find anything to confirm this.

Also, are the stdin buffers of grep and cut line buffered as well? I couldn't find anything to confirm if this is true or not but if it isn't line buffered then what is the point of making the stdout buffer line buffered if the stdin on the other side is block buffered?

[1] https://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

[2] https://blog.jpalardy.com/posts/grep-and-output-buffering/

Comment: `bash` doesn't buffer its output. Output is flushed after each command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffering is simply appending data to a byte string in memory so that you can coalesce multiple logical writes in a single `write()` syscall for efficiency. Since allocated memory is generally per process, a program will need to flush its buffers before it exits or the data will be lost.

For this reason, you necessarily can't buffer the output of multiple `/bin/echo` calls.

(These days `echo` is usually built into the shell, but it follows the same semantics.)